# How do I acess my Spider data from my main.py script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

Lets suppose that I have started a Scrapy project with this folder structure:

```
.root
├── main.py
├── scrapy.cfg
├── app
│  ├── items.py
│  ├── middlewares.py
│  ├── pipelines.py
│  ├── settings.py
│  └── spiders
│     ├── my_spider.py
```

So, in `main.py` file I have:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import scrapy
from app.spiders.my_spider import MySpider
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.settings import Settings
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
process.crawl(VultrSpider())
process.start()
```

It works fine when I run `./main.py` on terminal, but i have a few questions:

- How do I print my items' values instead of all Scrapy outputs?
- How do I access my data from `main.py`, supposing that I need to import the data to a Pandas DataFrame in `main.py`?

Comment: `scrapy` can save in `csv` file. So you can run `scrapy` with parameter which save in `csv` file and later you can load this `csv` to `pandas`.

Comment: maybe if you change [LOG_LEVEL](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#log-level) or [LOG_STDOUT](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#log-stdout) then you hide scrapy outputs

Comment: This is the only way ? I need to run my project with `./main.py`, which parameters did I put in `main.py` to export to .json or .csv files ? I know that I can run `scrapy crawl my_spider.py -o data.json` but I need to to this with my `main.py` file.

Comment: Cause like, my main file run the spider, get the data but i cant use this data. Lets suppose that in main file I need to treat the data before save in .JSON file for example. How can I do this ?

Comment: if you use `CrawlProcess` then you can do `CrawlerProcess({'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv', 'FEED_URI': 'output.csv' })` to save in `output.csv`

Comment: This is good, ill test here. Did u have any ideia if its possible to access the data after call `CrawlerProcess` in main without (or before) export to a `.csv` file ?

Comment: if you run `CrawlerProcess` in main thread then it blocks main.py till `CrawlerProcess` ends its job so you can't do anything before it save it in `csv`. If you will run `CrawlerProcess` in `thread` then you could use `queue` to communicate between two threads - but it can be more complicated. It is much simpler to wait for `csv` file and load it.

Comment: Thank you for the information, that was really helpful!

Comment: I agree with the above its easier to wait for the CSV and load it. Especially if you are not doing this hundreds of times and need it boot strapped. It's possible to handle the items as they come in but then you will need to use the signals and async callbacks built into the crawler processes. This will add a layer of probably unnecessary complexity to your program. I once did this to make an async API with twisted/klein.

Answer (score 3):

You can use pipelines for the purpose https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html

Just create a pipeline and insert your output or processing inside `process_item`

As for the Dataframes part, you can create/import a dataframe in `open_spider` and assign it to a self variable to be used across spider or in `process_item`

Using Pipelines is a better than putting the code anywhere else, because pipelines work like a buffer, suppose you scrape items at 100 items/sec and you process items at 10 items/sec, then using pipelines will not slow done the scraping, it'll rather queue up your scraped items in the pipelines.